# Inverse of Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am reading something that considers the following power series in $\mathbb{C}$:

$$ f(z) = z + a_2z^2 + a_3z^3 + a^4z^4 + ... \\ |z| < 1 $$

They define:

$$g(z) = z + b_0 + b_1z^{-1} + b_2z^{-2} + b_3z^{-3} + ... \\ |z| > 1 $$

And assert: $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z^{-1})}$ and $f(z) = \frac{1}{g(z^{-1})}$. I'm having trouble seeing this though. Ideas?

Comment: Is there a known relationship between the $a$s and the $b$s? It's certainly not true in general!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By direct calculation, we see that
\begin{align}
f(z^{-1}) =&\ \frac{1}{z}+a_2\frac{1}{z^2}+a_3\frac{1}{z^3}+\ldots=\ \frac{1}{z}\left(1+a_2\frac{1}{z}+a_3\frac{1}{z^2}+\ldots \right)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{f(z^{-1})} =&\  \frac{z}{1+\left(a_2\frac{1}{z}+a_3\frac{1}{z^2}+\ldots  \right)} = z\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\left( a_2\frac{1}{z}+a_3\frac{1}{z^2}+\ldots  \right)^n\\
=&\ z\left( 1+\sum^\infty_{k=1} b_{k-1}\frac{1}{z^k}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: how did you get the last equality in the second line?

Comment: Just regroup all the terms with $1/z$ to get $b_0$ coefficient; likewise, we regroup all the terms for the other $1/z^k$ to get $b_{k-1}$.

Comment: sorry, equality before that - I was counting lines from the very top!

Comment: i.e. how did you get this term: $z\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\left( a_2\frac{1}{z}+a_3\frac{1}{z^2}+\ldots  \right)^n$

Comment: I used the fact that $\frac{1}{1+y} = \sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n y^n$.

Comment: do we know, $(a_2\frac{1}{z} + a_3 \frac{1}{z^2} + ...)$ converges to a $y$?

Comment: Yes, since $|z|>1$ then $1/|z|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a relatively simple way of looking at the sums as geometric.  I assumed that $a_{0}$ and $b_{0}$ are equal to 1.  This is a more general way of looking at the problem, just to give you an idea!

This is a geometric power series $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}z^{i}$.   The common ratio is $z^{}$.

From a known formula, we can say that  $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}z^{i}$  = $\frac{1}{1-z_{}}$.  Although we cannot necessarily compute the inverse in finite terms, we can say that the inverse, $f(z^{-1})$, converges to

$\frac{-1}{z^{}}+1$.

Then, $\frac{1}{f(z^{-1})}$ = $\frac{1}{\frac{-1}{z^{}}+1}$= $\frac{z^{}}{z^{}-1}$.

Now all we have to do is to prove that $g(z)$ converges to $\frac{z^{}}{z^{}-1}$.  The common ratio for $g(z)$ is $z^{-1}$.  Using the previous formula, $g(z)$ converges to

$\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$=$\frac{z^{}}{z^{}-1}$.

The other argument is similar to the one above.  I hope this helps!